# Nginx 301 Redirect not working correctly

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

I'm trying to redirect all traffic from one subfolder to another.  For example:

```
www.website.com/ve/12345.html
```

to

```
www.website.com/es/12345.html
```

My nginx command:

```
rewrite ^/(ve)/(.*)$ /es/$1 permanent;
```

Does the following:

```
www.website.com/ve/12345.html
```

to

```
www.website.com/es/ve
```

How can I replace ve with es and keep the rest of the URL intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've used $1 in your replacement, but $1 is just the characters 've', not the extra stuff at the end, which is in $2 in your version.

Best would be to remove the extra capture group so that you're not capturing things you're not using. This rule will do the redirect ok:

```
rewrite ^/ve/(.+)$ /es/$1 permanent;
```